# How to move character in pygame without filling background

Tags: python, pygame

My game has a game board that the programme initially sets up based on the user's desired dimensions. It looks like this:

```py
def drawGrid():
    global BLOCKSIZE
    BLOCKSIZE = 40 #Set the size of the grid block - should be evenly divisible by window size
    for x in range(windowSize[0]):
        for y in range(windowSize[1]):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x * BLOCKSIZE, y * BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE, rect, 1)
```

In the game loop, I want to move an image but without filling the screen with black each time (as then I would have to call drawGrid() many times, and is not efficient). How could I do this?

**Edit:** The image fits in a square. I also need a pygame.draw.circle() to move along the lines of the grid.

Comment: Does the image fit in one grid square or across multiple?

Comment: So you want to draw the image in a new grid square and fill in the old grid square?

Comment: I want to draw the image in a new grid square and remove it from the old square without using screen.fill()

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far. Like the code for putting the image on the grid

Comment: Instead of drawing the entire grid line by line directly to the screen every time, why not just use a separate Surface to store the grid once it's drawn and blit that every frame?

Comment: if you would have backgroud as separated surface then you could copy only part used by player in old place. You can also try copy part of the background from current surface before you put player and copy it back when player leave this place. Even `pygame.display.update()` may do something like this - it can get list of `Rect` with regions which it has to copy from original background to current surface to remove only some elements. But it needs background as surface. But frankly copy full background surface to current surface can be more effective because it may use optimized code.

Comment: @TechPerson I have no idea how I could no have thought of this, but `currentGridScreen = SCREEN.copy()` did exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: No problem! I moved my comment to an answer so others who see this post know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved my comment into an answer to help others who may come across this problem.

A solution would be just to draw the grid to another Surface and blit that to the screen every frame. This could be implemented most easily by making a copy of the screen with `screenCopy = screen.copy()` after drawing the grid and saving it to another variable to blit later. Just make sure to re-draw the grid surface when the window size or grid size changes.